# Javascript : Throw error when Chinese characters are in the file name

Tags: javascript, regex, file-upload, filenames, chinese-locale

Hi I would like to throw an error when I see Chinese characters in a file name using Javascript. My code throws an "Expected Hexadecimal Digit" error. So far I have the following code:

```
if(document.f1.Attachment.value.match(""/[\u4e00-\u9fff]|[\u3400-\u4dbf]|[\u{20000}-\u{2a6df}]|[\u{2a700}-\u{2b73f}]|[\u{2b740}-\u{2b81f}]|[\u{2b820}-\u{2ceaf}]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u3300-\u33ff]|[\ufe30-\ufe4f]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u{2f800}-\u{2fa1f}]""))
{
alert('Attachment cannot contain Chinese characters');
}
```

I was reading up and understood this is because of \u but I do not understand how I could fix this.

Comment: You have everything wrapped in `""` instead of `"`.

Comment: No, you do not need the double quotes, remove `""` from both ends. Also, you have `\u{2b820}`, so you need to use `u` modifier. It means, it is a regex to be used with ES6 JS environment. `if(document.f1.Attachment.value.match(/[\u4e00-\u9fff]|[\u3400-\u4dbf]|[\u{20000}-\u{2a6df}]|[\u{2a700}-\u{2b73f}]|[\u{2b740}-\u{2b81f}]|[\u{2b820}-\u{2ceaf}]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u3300-\u33ff]|[\ufe30-\ufe4f]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u{2f800}-\u{2fa1f}]/u))`. See  [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1ampxgw/), it works in FF and Chrome. If the text is part of some string literal, you might need to double escape ``\``.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : I see your fiddle and works perfect. Exactly what I want. But doesn't seem to work for me. I added one by one to check where it was breaking and the javascript error thrown now seems to be because of the { and } symbol. Any suggestions on why this might be ?

Comment: Try [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/b1ampxgw/5/). `/[\u4e00-\u9fff\u3400-\u4dbf\uf900-\ufaff\u3300-\u33ff\ufe30-\ufe4f\uf900-\ufaff]|(?:[\uD840-\uD868\uD86A-\uD872][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDEDF\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD873[\uDC00-\uDEAF]|\uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1F])/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should remove `""` from both ends of a regex literal. In JS, you need to use plain `/.../` with no `"` or `'` wrapping the construct for it to work properly, to be parsed as a regex.

Next, your pattern contains `\u{XXXXX}` notation that is compliant with the ECMAScript 6+ standard, and requires `u` modifier to work in the compatible JS environment. So, in ES6, this is a valid solution:

```
.match(/[\u4e00-\u9fff]|[\u3400-\u4dbf]|[\u{20000}-\u{2a6df}]|[\u{2a700}-\u{2b73f}]|[\u{2b740}-\u{2b81f}]|[\u{2b820}-\u{2ceaf}]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u3300-\u33ff]|[\ufe30-\ufe4f]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u{2f800}-\u{2fa1f}]/u)
```

To make it work in ES5, older browsers, you need to [*transpile* the regex](https://mothereff.in/regexpu):

```
.match(/[\u4e00-\u9fff\u3400-\u4dbf\uf900-\ufaff\u3300-\u33ff\ufe30-\ufe4f\uf900-\ufaff]|(?:[\uD840-\uD868\uD86A-\uD872][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDEDF\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD873[\uDC00-\uDEAF]|\uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1F])/)
```

JS ES5 demo:

```js
if("中文".match(/[\u4e00-\u9fff\u3400-\u4dbf\uf900-\ufaff\u3300-\u33ff\ufe30-\ufe4f\uf900-\ufaff]|(?:[\uD840-\uD868\uD86A-\uD872][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDEDF\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD873[\uDC00-\uDEAF]|\uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1F])/)) {
  console.log("ES5: Chinese detected!");
}
```

JS ES6 demo:

```js
if("中文".match(/[\u4e00-\u9fff]|[\u3400-\u4dbf]|[\u{20000}-\u{2a6df}]|[\u{2a700}-\u{2b73f}]|[\u{2b740}-\u{2b81f}]|[\u{2b820}-\u{2ceaf}]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u3300-\u33ff]|[\ufe30-\ufe4f]|[\uf900-\ufaff]|[\u{2f800}-\u{2fa1f}]/u)) {
  console.log("ES6: Chinese detected!");
}
```

This last one gives *Invalid range in character set* error in IE since it does not support ES6.

Comment: This is perfect ! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help !